# Select multiple DIVs with same name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to select similarly named class name or ID if there are in the same direct parent, meaning if there are in the same box, proof https://codepen.io/akpobi/pen/poPddMr. But if there are more boxes and I'm trying to target all the buttons in their separate parents, it doesn't work. Help.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const box = document.querySelector(".box");

const boxInternal = document.querySelector(".box-internal").childNodes;

const popFunc = function(event) {
  for (const boxInternals of boxInternal) {
    if (event.target == boxInternals) {
      box.classList.toggle("box-scale");
    }
  }
};

btn.addEventListener("click", popFunc, false)
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What behavior are you trying to achieve here? `for (boxInternals of boxInternal) {` is missing `const` so you're declaring a global.

Comment: Well, true but I don't think it's actually that important in this snippet of what I'm trying to achieve. I can't verbally explain what I'm trying to achieve that well. Let's say there's more button in that "box-internal" class, I can select all of them but if the second box div have buttons too, I can't select them.

Comment: No, but it might cause problems in your app later so you might as well fix it. `popFunc` is also global, and `===` is preferred over `==`. What should happen to the boxes when you click a button?

Comment: I know bro, I'm not actually using it in a project but learning how to manipulate div.

Comment: Try always to use `<button type="button"` (by muscle-memory) since by default button type is `"submit"` - not super-necessary in that specific case but helps avoid issues on the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.closest(".box")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the closest enclosing box to the event target, then toggle the desired class on it:

```js
for (const btn of document.querySelectorAll(".btn")) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    evt.target.closest(".box").classList.toggle("box-scale");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #0a0a16;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
}

.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(18, 18, 37);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.box-scale {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55452921/6243352) in the parent element:

```js
document.querySelector(".box-wrapper")
  .addEventListener("click", ({target: el}) => {
    el.closest(".btn")
     ?.closest(".box")
     ?.classList
      .toggle("box-scale")
    ;
  })
;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #0a0a16;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
}

.box-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(18, 18, 37);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.box-scale {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-internal">
      <button class="btn">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this is part of a form, you might want to [disable submit with `type="button"` attributes on your buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904199/whats-the-point-of-button-type-button).