# Is there a need to state type="submit" for a button when the button is used in a form?

Tags: html

I am new to programming please forgive me if my question is out of place or if it does not follow community guidelines.

I was following a youtube tutorial and this is the simplified code:

```
<form class="form" id="form">
  <input type="text" id="input" autocomplete="off"/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My question is why is there a need to state **type="submit"** ? I tried removing the type and it seems to work fine.

Also, I saw [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904199/whats-the-point-of-button-type-button) on StackOverflow that states the default for button when it is used in a form is already submit.

Is the person in the tutorial just being thorough or is there another reason as to why it needs to be stated?

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to because `button`'s default `type` is `submit`.

But, you have to because your purpose is not writing something that "just works". You read code 90% of time and write code 10% of time, so readability is **essential**. (though there are some [weird places](https://www.ioccc.org/) where the purpose is exactly the opposite, but that's an edge case)

If the form is so large that you don't know if your submit button is inside the form or not, simply stating `type="submit"` will give you a clear idea that it's inside a form.

There are *many* more examples in coding that you simply write "unnecessary" code for documentation purpose, such as naming a function `catchButterfly()` instead of `f()`.

In general, it's always a good practice to be **VERY verbose and explicit** about every piece of code you write because it's just a few extra lines of code but the advantage is HUGE.

Comment: This is a nice answer. It also helps with learning. I'm a beginner at HTML (few months) and the verbose approach helps make concepts explicit and stick in your mind when learning (as opposed to knowing the default, implicit behaviour for things) and also helps when looking back at old code.

Comment: Yeah, you'll be amazed at how little you remember about the code you wrote only 6 months ago. It's almost as if looking at someone else's code.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing things up for me, really appreciate it.

Comment: @technophyle thank you for reminding me I have marked it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

`<button type="submit">` and `<button>` are the same thing.

The reason is the default type of a button is submit.

So you can leave it off if you want. If you do not want the button to submit the form, then you want to use `type="button"`.

It is explained in the [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) or [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html)

Answer (score 1):

It works fine when removed because submit is the default type :

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type