# Page reloads on button click while event.preventDefault() is used

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

i tried making a class to create some transactions. I wanted to fill out the values. whenever the button was clicked it would trigger the this.handleClick function to create a new transaction and log this to the console. however, the page automatically reloads whenever i submit the values. what am i doing wrong? here is code used.

```js
class Transaction {
    constructor(getal, afzender, ontvanger) {
        this.getal = getal;
        this.afzender = afzender;
        this.ontvanger = ontvanger;
        // Set the clicker
        this.button = document.getElementById('clicker');
        this.button.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
    }

    print() {
        console.log(`${this.afzender} sent ${this.getal} bits to ${this.ontvanger}`);
    }

    emptyInputs() {
        document.querySelector('#bedrag').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#verzender').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#ontvanger').value = '';
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const p = document.querySelector('.confirmation');
        p.style.color = 'green';
        const bedrag = document.querySelector('#bedrag').value;
        const verzender = document.querySelector('#verzender').value;
        const ontvanger = document.querySelector('#ontvanger').value;
        const transaction = new Transaction(bedrag, verzender, ontvanger);
        transaction.print(); // Optionally, print the transaction details
        transaction.emptyInputs(); // Clear the input fields
        p.innerText = "Transaction made!";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
        <h2>Maak een transactie</h2>
        <form class="form-group">
            <div>
                <label for="bedrag">Bedrag:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="bedrag" name="bedrag">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="verzender">Verzender:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="verzender" name="verzender">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="ontvanger">Ontvanger:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ontvanger" name="ontvanger">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="clicker" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 ">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p class="confirmation"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="Transaction.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `return false;` in handleClick to prevent form submission.

Comment: Because it's not `click` event that is causing the page to reload. It's `submit` event. You should listen for `submit` on the form and not `click` on the button

Comment: no its fine, heres a jsbin, https://jsbin.com/diwilirupi/edit?html,js,

Comment: Tried all of the above but didnt solve the issue. for some reason the exact same code does work on jsbin though..

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but have you tried changing the `type` of your `button` element to `button` instead of `submit` to prevent the form from submitting?  
Check out: [What's the point of <button type="button">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904199/whats-the-point-of-button-type-button)

Comment: I changed the button and it does not refresh the page. however, the data does not get logged.

Answer (score 0):

You change the event listener so that it listens for the submit event:

```js
class Transaction {
    constructor(getal, afzender, ontvanger) {
        this.getal = getal;
        this.afzender = afzender;
        this.ontvanger = ontvanger;
        // Set the clicker
        this.form = document.forms.form01;
        this.form.addEventListener('submit', this.handleSubmit);
    }

    print() {
        console.log(`${this.afzender} sent ${this.getal} bits to ${this.ontvanger}`);
    }

    emptyInputs() {
        document.querySelector('#bedrag').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#verzender').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#ontvanger').value = '';
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const p = document.querySelector('.confirmation');
        p.style.color = 'green';
        const bedrag = document.querySelector('#bedrag').value;
        const verzender = document.querySelector('#verzender').value;
        const ontvanger = document.querySelector('#ontvanger').value;
        const transaction = new Transaction(bedrag, verzender, ontvanger);
        transaction.print(); // Optionally, print the transaction details
        transaction.emptyInputs(); // Clear the input fields
        p.innerText = "Transaction made!";
    }
}

const transaction = new Transaction("", "", "");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
        <h2>Maak een transactie</h2>
        <form name="form01" class="form-group">
            <div>
                <label for="bedrag">Bedrag:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="bedrag" name="bedrag">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="verzender">Verzender:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="verzender" name="verzender">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="ontvanger">Ontvanger:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ontvanger" name="ontvanger">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="clicker" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 ">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p class="confirmation"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="Transaction.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```